# Using email_exists() wp function in an ajax request

Tags: functions, ajax, email

I'm requesting the wordpress function `if (email_exists($email)) { ... }` from a file (email_check.php) via ajax. Using this function is causing a server error though.

The origin (from an input text field):

```
var check = $('#email-input');
var email = check.val();
$.ajax({
    url: "email_check.php",
    data: {'email' : email},
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.result) {
            alert('Email exists!');
        }
        else {
            alert('Email doesnt!');
        }
    },
    error: function(data){
        //error
    }
});
```

check_email.php

```
$email = $_GET['email'];
if ( email_exists($email) ) {$response->result = true;} else {$response->result = false;}
echo json_encode($response);
```

This results in no alert taking place. By going directly to `check_email.php?email=email@address.com` it give me a server error page. I also replaced `email_exists($email)` with the same direct email entered as the url param and it does work.

Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the PHP file you are using has no connection to WordPress, the function is never loaded. Use the [built-in AJAX-API](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9231/whats-the-preferred-method-of-writing-ajax-enabled-plugins) instead, and it will work fine.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Would it not work to simply reference where the function is? Or not good practise?

Comment: Most WordPress files require other WordPress files to be included without an error. In the end you would include almost as many files as the AJAX file already does.

Comment: For anyone else interested, I ended up following http://w4dev.com/wp/wp_ajax to get it all working. Thanks toscho for the solution.